# Adding buildings to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I want to add buildings/outlines of buildings to google maps(for better accuracy when retrieving information via google's location api since the address api looks at this data)

What is the current 2018 method to do this?

It used to be easy using google maps maker but that is not available anymore.

Also if i have data available to me, is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: I just found this: https://maps.google.com/intl/en/help/maps/citiesin3d/dataguidelines.html. Don't know if this is what you're looking for or not, but if it is, let me know and I'll gather more info to expand it into an answer.

Comment: This question now has 1k views but no upvotes or answers lol

Answer (score 3):

OpenStreetMap has vectorized roads, buildings, etc. with tons of attributes in the data tables as well.  Get a free account and read here to learn how to download the vector data, whether you want 1 block or the entire world.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Then use this tool to convert the .osm to .kml, and open in Google Maps (My Maps).

https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/osm-to-kml

Comment: this does not answer my question, i want to add the building to google maps and make it visible to everyone, not display it lcally

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I think polygon editing on Google maps was disabled in around 2015.  The terrain map type API would probably show at least some building outlines.  Don't know if that is of any relevance or not.

Comment: @pipeline_usa thanks for the info but that leads me to a follow up question -how are buildings updated on google maps now? there must be "some" internal process they follow...Open street maps has more detail right now in india than google maps

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan my guess is photogrammetry

Comment: I know that Street View data is one source of it. So if there's no Street View imagery (or there is, but it's outdated) then one could obtain the appropriate equipment (at least a 360° camera with integrated GPS and compass, I don't know full requirements), use it to collect new Street View imagery and contribute that, and that might theoretically lead to building geometry being updated after a while.

Comment: Street view was banned in india so...i've tried submitting data via the link you posted at https://maps.google.com/intl/en/help/maps/citiesin3d/dataguidelines.html but i don't think anyone is reviewing those applications. no human response ever(for india/kuwait).